# Set attributes of Keras layer afterwards

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, regularized

I have a customized regularizer which needs the model output tensor to be analyzed. The basically I can't put in this way.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, name="dense_1", W_regularizer=Custom(0.1)))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, name='dense_2'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(..)
```

Where the custom function needs the target label tensor and unfortunately such tensor is not implemented yet.

I also try to set attribute of such layer:

```
model.add(Dense(128, name="dense_1"))
model.get_layer('dense_1').W_regularizer = Custom(0.1)
```

When `get_config()` of such layer I see it has been applied correctly but seems not work during the training. Or perhaps this way is not a wise way to implement.

Answer (score 0):

To change something like this you need to recompile the model. This is because the compile process generates the training function to be minimized afterwards. To change the training function you need to compile again.

Just call

```
model.compile(...)
```

after your changes and it should work the way you expect it to work.

Comment: neither this way can't do the correct job. ah.. i'm editing (wait)

Comment: just put my current findings in comment. thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Thomas, i tried re-compiling but not work as expected (as first one shown below)

i tried the following method..
1) directly specify (work)

```
#put inf number here for testing
x = Dense(128,name="dense_1", W_regularizer = l2(1E300))
model.add(x)
...
model.compile(...)
```

2) set attribute afterwards and compile (not working)

```
x = Dense(128,name="dense_1")
model.add(x)
x.W_regularizer = l2(1E300)
...
model.compile(...)
```

3) using `add_weight` in topology.layer (it works)

```
x = Dense(128,name="dense_1")
model.add(x)
x.W = x.add_weight((x.input_dim, x.output_dim),
               initializer='zero',
               name='{}_W'.format(x.name),
               constraint=x.W_constraint,
               regularizer=l2(1E300))
model.compile(...)
```

for 1) 3) i got `loss: nan` which implies that the modification is successful applied and 3) is what i want. while second one don't. but there's must be a smart way to achieve.